# Dynamically generated GET request to an external database

Tags: rest, jsf, get

I'm asking for help to my problem. I am new to JSF and I have a simple JSF online store demo page. I don't even use navigation rules since I only include the page with search results beneath the searching tags fields. The problem is a have sth like 15 fields (input texts and menus) to perform a detailed search. After selecting the fields and clicking on the search button I have to generate a long GET request for the database (which is located on a different server than my page and uses REST), receive the response (xml format), extract the search results and publish them on the page. The search patter is sth like this:

http://serveradress/search/ [x1][x2][x3]....[xn]

Where x1-xn are the values for the search engine and have to be read from the page's fields, so it has to be generated dynamically. The get request can be very long since there are 15 fields and one can have some additional options. The data base is on a different server and responds with an xml script with search results.

I found some solutions on the internet on how to perform a GET request using params but don't really know how can it fit to my problem since I have to receive the results from an external data base and manage them rather inside the java bean for publishing (i do not want to change the url adres of my page).

I am using JSF 1.2, with Eclipse IDE and JBoss on Ubuntu. The search request has to be GET since the data base uses that REST interface.

I am asking for your help in this matter if someone is able to find a solution to this problem or provide me with some link. I would strongly appreciate an example code with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use JBOSS resteasy RESTful API's